# How can I separate the output of SQL tables using SQL UNION?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables in one database, with each table containing the exact same column names. I'm using SQL UNION in order to pull every record from all of those tables, and output the records onto a web page. Each record is output between a div with an ID of 'contributors.'

What I am ultimately tying to do is set some sort of separation between each table that is being output, so that I don't have every record within a table seamlessly running into the next table.

I tried to echo a div before the 'contributors' div, but that did not work. Does anyone have any idea how I can output data from issue1, then create a heading to  below to separate issue1 from issue2?

```
<?php

$res=mysql_query('
SELECT First, Last, Title, StoryLink, Genre, About, Link, Picture, ALT FROM issue1 UNION ALL
SELECT First, Last, Title, StoryLink, Genre, About, Link, Picture, ALT FROM issue2 UNION ALL
SELECT First, Last, Title, StoryLink, Genre, About, Link, Picture, ALT FROM issue3
');
if (!$res) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$cont_img_path = $img_path.end(explode('/', $row['Picture']));
if(file_exists($cont_img_path))
{
?>
    <div class="contributors">
        <h6><?php echo $row['First']; ?> <?php echo $row['Last']; ?></h6>
        <h2 style="color:#ffffff;"><em><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></em></h2>
        <p style="color:#ffd997;"><?php echo $row['Genre']; ?></p>

<h3 class="ctr-image"><a href="<?php echo $row['Picture']; ?>" id="3e-fancybox" name="<?php echo $row['First'] .' '. $row['Last']; ?>" StoryLink="<?php echo $row['StoryLink']; ?>" Ptitle="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>" genre="<?php echo $row['Genre']; ?>" about="<?php echo str_replace('"', '&#34;', ($row['About'])); ?>" WebLink="<?php echo $row['Link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['Picture']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['ALT']; ?>"></a></h3>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: So you are doing UNION with three different tables that have the same column names?

Comment: Yes, and everything is getting pulled onto the page, I just can't separate the tables.

Comment: Instead of doing UNION, could you JOIN the tables with themselves? Is there a way of joining them?

Comment: I tried that, but I kept getting duplicates, everything was very messy.

Comment: If you are getting duplicates, use distinct. If you explain the relationship between the tables, we can help you build the query. Maybe you are using the wrong join (inner, left or right join)

Comment: The tables are made up of simple information such as first name, last name, issue title, a url to a picture. Each table is storing names of contributors to issue1, the same thing for issue2 table. Every table uses the exact same column names. I am trying to group this data by issue/table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107911/discussion-between-marlon-and-erick).

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding that if you want three separate results sets, it makes more sense to use AJAX and make three separate requests, here is a solution:

```
$res = mysql_query('
SELECT 
      'Issue1' as context,
      First, 
      Last, 
      Title, 
      StoryLink, 
      Genre, 
      About, 
      Link, 
      Picture, 
      ALT 
FROM 
    issue1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      'Issue2' as context,
      First, 
      Last, 
      Title, 
      StoryLink, 
      Genre, 
      About, 
      Link, 
      Picture, 
      ALT 
FROM 
    issue2 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      'Issue3' as context,
      First, 
      Last, 
      Title, 
      StoryLink, 
      Genre, 
      About, 
      Link, 
      Picture, 
      ALT 
FROM 
      issue3
)';
```

This solves the question, as asked, however I'm not convinced your database structure is correct to begin with.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but looking at the part 'as context,' will that work with MySQL?

Comment: @Marlon I use select `'something' as some_other_thing` in mysql all the time in production, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of a Union is to have it return one set of seamless results.

Aside from running three separate queries to get the results, you might could count the number of rows each query returns and add a `<br/>` tag or something in your while loop when a counter reaches the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your query eg:

```
SELECT Title, 'issue1' FROM issue1 UNION ALL
SELECT Title, 'issue2' FROM issue2
```

Then your code could be somthing like

```
print header for 'issue1'
for each 'issue1' in results
    display row
print header for 'issue2'
for each 'issue2' in results
    display row
```